# For loop printing echo command only once

Tags: shell-script, grep, arguments, for

In this small for loop I created, I need the loop to print this message only once for all arguments.

```
for arg in $@
do
        echo "There are $(grep "$arg" cis132Students|wc -l) classmates in this list, where $(wc -l cis132Students) is the actual number of classmates."
done
```

What contains in $arg is a few names that do exist in the file, and a couple of names that do not exist in the file.
What happens is that the loops prints that message multiple times for each argument, where I only want it to print once.

Comment: By using `$@` the parameters are expanded to a separste word and then `grep` is run for each one which is why the message is repeated for each instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to loop through the arguments, this is reading them one at a time causing your echo statement to execute once for each argument.

You can do something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

student_file=cis132Students
p=$(echo "$@" | tr ' ' '|')
ln=$(wc -l "$student_file")
gn=$(grep -cE "$p" "$student_file")

echo "There are $gn classmates in the list, where $ln is the actual number of classmates."
```

---

`p`: Will be converted into a string that can be fed to grep in extended regex mode.  For example if you provide arguments: `jesse jay` it will be convered to `jesse|jay`
`ln`: Will be the total number of lines (students) in your input file
`gn`: Will be the number of students that have matched your argument search

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
$ cat cis132Students
peter
paul
mary
$ cat file
peter
mary
lucy
$ echo "There are $(grep -cf file cis132Students) classmates in this list, where $(wc -l <cis132Students) is the actual number of classmates."
There are 2 classmates in this list, where 3 is the actual number of classmates.
```

- `grep -cf file cis132Students`: parameter `-f file` takes `file` as pattern input file for `grep` and `-c` counts the matching lines
- `wc -l <cis132Students` outputs the line count without the filename